# selecting from linked server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I'm having an issue i'm not really understanding...
I am querying a sql table joined with a linked server and the select works fine when I 'select *' 
[image]

But as soon as I start selecting individual columns I get an error:
[image]

It does not matter where the column comes from, SQLserver or from the linked server, trying to any column by name results in this error...

```
select DiscrepancyID 
from (select distinct * 
      from 
      (Select  Discrepancy.*
             , cast(id as varchar) as id
             , me2.d
             , tailnumber
             , me2.fleet_code 
       From Discrepancy, 
            openquery(AIROPS, 'Select aircraftid as id
                                    , tailnumber
                                    , oagactype
                                    , operator 
                               FROM AIROPS.AIRCRAFT') airops 
        join openquery(meprd, 'Select equipment
                                    , REGEXP_SUBSTR(sceptre_fleet_description, ''[[:digit:]]{3}'' ) as d 
                               FROM ME_DWH.FLEET_CODES') me 
         on (airops.operator+' '+ airops.oagactype) = REPLACE(me.equipment, '  ',' ') 
         join openquery(meprd, 'Select fleet_code
                                     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(sceptre_fleet_description, ''[[:digit:]]{3}'' ) as d 
                                FROM ME_DWH.FLEET_CODES 
                                Where fleet_code != ''NA''') me2 
         on me.d = me2.d) link1) link
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Presumably the columns you are naming are not in the table.  Perhaps they have hidden characters, such as spaces at the end of the name.

Comment: So, is it really a column named `DiscrepancyId`?

Comment: that may have been the case but I just went and ran 'select DiscrepancyID from Discrepancy' and was able to find the ID#s just fine, also going into the OracleDBs that are linked and selecting columns by name works fine

Comment: yes there is a column named DiscrepancyID